# SQL, AND, OR in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to solve this, but I can't get it right.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `users` 
WHERE (
   fname LIKE  '%Toms%'
   OR lname LIKE  '%Toms%'
)
AND (
   bDate <1991 /12 /03
   AND regDate >2000 /12 /03
   AND lastActivity >2000 /12 /03
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

What I want is to get users with name or last name 'Toms' who are born before 1991, but registered after 2000. All I get is all users with name 'Toms', like there is not a second part to the query!

What am I missing here?

Comment: Dates. please provide under single quotes '1991/12/03'

Comment: Already tried, does not solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of your dates are wrong and are not enclosed in quotes. Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `users` 
WHERE (
   fname LIKE  '%Toms%'
   OR lname LIKE  '%Toms%'
)
AND (
   bDate < "1991-12-03"
   AND regDate > "2000-12-03"
   AND lastActivity > "2000-12-03"
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Does not matter, same problem!

Comment: @user2945241 What type are the date columns?

Comment: @user2945241 I've created an SQL fiddle showing the above query running: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f42f2/1

Comment: I don't know what was the problem, but i played around yesterday, and now it works, i recreated tables, so maybe the TYPE was problem. but thx :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE ( fname LIKE '%Toms%'
    OR lname LIKE '%Toms%')
    AND (bDate < '1991-12-03'
     AND regDate > '2000-12-03'
     AND lastActivity > '2000-12-03')
LIMIT 0, 30
```

You columns bDate,regDate and lastActivity should be DATE type.
Else if it is datetime type

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE ( fname LIKE '%Toms%'
    OR lname LIKE '%Toms%')
    AND (DATE(bDate) < '1991-12-03'
     AND DATE(regDate) > '2000-12-03'
     AND DATE(lastActivity) > '2000-12-03')
LIMIT 0, 30
```